# Convenient ways to initialize nested fields with lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have some data type which is very similar to ordinary trees, just some specialized form.

```
data NestedTree = NT
    { _dummy :: Int
    , _tree  :: HashMap String NestedTree
    } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''NestedTree
```

I want to initialize instances of my data type imperatively using lenses. Here is what I got now:

```
example :: NestedTree
example = flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do
    dummy .= 3
    tree.at "foo" ?= flip execState (NT 0 mempty) (dummy .= 10)
```

You can observe in this example that I can replace first `(NT 0 mempty)` with `(NT 3 mempty)` but this is not the point. What I want is too be able to initialize nested `HashMap`s using this nice imperative style. More precise, I want to be able to write something like this:

```
example :: NestedTree
example = flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do
    dummy .= 3
    tree.at "foo" ?= flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do
        dummy .= 10
        tree.at "foo nested" ?= NT 5 mempty
    tree.at "bar" ?= flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do
        dummy .= 15
        tree.at "bar nested" ?= NT (-3) mempty
```

My real data structure is more complex and it very soon becomes really ugly to initialize it using just simple records. Thus I want to use some kind of DSL, and lenses fit quite good for my need. But you can notice that code above doesn't compile.

It's because `($)` has lowest precedence and I can't just write `tree.at "foo" ?= flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do`. But I really don't want to add `()` around nested `do`s.

Is there any nice ways to mix arbitrary operators with `$` and `do` in order to write such functions? I really don't want to introduce some helper like `wordsAssign = (?=)` and call functions like

`wordsAssign (tree.at "foo") $ flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do`

because I like `?=` operator. Maybe I'm doing everything wrong and this kind of things I want to do can be done without lenses with some hand-written operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) is tailor-made for handling nested state updates. In your case, unfortunately, the `Maybe`-ness makes using it slightly awkward:

```
example :: NestedTree
example = flip execState (NT 0 mempty) $ do
    dummy .= 3
    zoom (tree.at "foo") $ do
        put (Just (NT 0 mempty))
        _Just.dummy .= 10
        _Just.tree.at "foo nested" ?= NT 5 mempty
    -- Or, using zoom one more time:
    zoom (tree.at "bar") $ do
        put (Just (NT 0 mempty))
        zoom _Just $ do
            dummy .= 15
            tree.at "bar nested" ?= NT (-3) mempty
```

For the sake of comparison, if you didn't need to insert new keys at the outer level, you would be able to use [`ix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix) instead of `at` and drop all the `Maybe`-related boilerplate:

```
    zoom (tree.ix "foo") $ do
        dummy .= 10
        tree.at "foo nested" ?= NT 5 mempty
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this approach and it works like magic. If anybody interested: utility function to help me with zooming (https://github.com/serokell/log-warper/blob/91d82ed1b3a331ed4a8e0f458390f985028d1817/src/System/Wlog/LoggerConfig.hs#L120) and here how I use it (https://github.com/serokell/log-warper/blob/91d82ed1b3a331ed4a8e0f458390f985028d1817/test/Test/Wlog/RollingSpec.hs#L69)

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `?=` with the same precedence as `$` to make them play nice together:

```
import Control.Lens hiding ((?=))
import qualified Control.Lens as L

(?=)
  :: MonadState s m
  => ASetter s s a (Maybe b) -> b -> m ()
(?=) = (L.?=)

infixr 0 ?=
```

With this your example works.